# matAutocomplete control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5, angular-material-6

Can't find the issue.. It works but presents error and opens values after a bit of scroll.. 
Anyone?

> control.registerOnChange is not a function

```js
searchPort: FormControl = new FormControl();
searchPortResult = [];
...


this.searchPort.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(400))
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.codeTableSrv.searchport(data)
      .subscribe(response => this.searchPortResult = response);
  });

updatePortCode(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
  if (event.option.value !== undefined) {
    this.form.patchValue({
      portCode: {
        id: event.option.value.id,
        code: event.option.value.code,
        description: event.option.value.description,
        region: event.option.value.region
      }
    });
  }
}

displayPortFn(item) {
  if (item == null) {
    return '';
  }
  return item.code + ' ' + item.description;
}


createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({     
      portCode: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required],
        code: ['', Validators.required],
        description: ['', Validators.required],
        region: ['', Validators.required],
      }),    
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" 
    placeholder="Search port" 
    aria-label="Number" 
    matInput 
    formControlName="portCode" 
    [formControl]="searchPort" 
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionSelected)="updatePortCode($event)" 
    [displayWith]="displayPortFn">
      <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let item of searchPortResult" 
      [value]="item">
        {{ item.code + ' ' + item.description }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Need an example of how to change my code to make it work without the warning . 
the code is operational other than the stated error. 
it doesn't holt the process and enables yet to get autocomplete values as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `FormControl` twice via `formControlName` and `formControl`. `searchPort` overrides `portCode` from your `form`. Since your code works fine you can just remove `formControlName` attribute.

```
<div class="col-6">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" 
    placeholder="Search port" 
    aria-label="Number" 
    matInput
    [formControl]="searchPort" 
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionSelected)="updatePortCode($event)" 
    [displayWith]="displayPortFn">
      <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let item of searchPortResult" 
      [value]="item">
        {{ item.code + ' ' + item.description }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ji9jh3)

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Comment: Seems that was the answer I gave two weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't specify a `formControlName` and a `formControl` for the same input. Plus, your `formControlName` value points to a `FormGroup` when it should point to a `FormControl`. So get rid of `formControlName`:

```
<div class="col-6">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" 
    placeholder="Search port" 
    aria-label="Number" 
    matInput 
    [formControl]="searchPort" 
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionSelected)="updatePortCode($event)" 
    [displayWith]="displayPortFn">
      <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let item of searchPortResult" 
      [value]="item">
        {{ item.code + ' ' + item.description }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of either the formControl or the formControlName option. See https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.

Comment: how can i read of them ? - search port is the one listening to the values and the portCode is where the value is updated when chosen.. 

Tried to remove them but it stopped working. 
Now at least it works but with terrible warning as stated, but works..